# Geokit plugin auto zoom level calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geokit

i'm using GEOKIT plug-in in my rails project. i want to display 10 points in a  geo image.i've faced a problem with my zoom level .my zoom level is fully depend on my 10 points distance. if distance is small then zoom level should be high. and opposite my zoom level need to be low. but problem is that 10 points distance varying a big range. now my question is that is there any idea or method in GEOKIT to auto calculated zoom level depending distance? 
     
        thanks in advance  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okk. i've complete it. it was Mapping.rb file error.